# I need help getting recaptcha to work

Tags: php, security, captcha

I recenlty had a site designed for me, but my dev used a really crappy generic captcha that fails half the time.  I'm trying to replace it using a recaptcha, but I'm having trouble.  I cannot figure out which *.php is used for 'processing' and which is used for the 'form'.

I didn't want to post the whole code, so here it is:

This is the 'form' page, as it has the form fields and etc embedded:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45666699/formcode.txt

Can someone please take a look at this code and tell me where I should put the private code for recaptcha?  Also, how do I disable the "random_number" captcha that is already installed?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you have mistaken this site for vWorker or elance

Answer (score 0):

the code for your existing captcha is on line `295, 296 and 297`

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "6LfIUdISAAAAAKguxgdPCjZ6-OkVeu5tmcBaa7ug"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need the private key when you're trying to validate that the correct captch was entered (i.e. at the point where you're handling the form submission)

Which by looking at your code should start immediately after `line 4`

Using a project i did a while back, you would have something like so...

```
$recaptcha_error = NULL;
//set it to NULL initially
if(isset($_POST["btnsend"])){
    include_once(INCLUDES_FOLDER."recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php");
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer(RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if($resp->is_valid){
        //captch was gotten correctly
        //continue with your normal code processing here
    } else {
        //wrong input -- captch was invalid -- give the person the error response
        //mine is as below -- my usual way :)
        $response = array(array("Something seems to be wrong with the captcha!","Please check that you entered it correctly or check the returned error message"),false,"w");
        $recaptcha_error = $resp->error;
        //make sure to do the above so u can use it when generating the captcha display
    }
}


//You got the recaptch error (or left it as NULL above so you could do this)
//when generating your captch display as done on your lines 295, 296, 297
include_once(INCLUDES_FOLDER."recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php");
echo recaptcha_get_html(RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY,$recaptcha_error);
```

Hope this helps (even if a little) :)
Cheers